# How to replace current branch's head with specific commit in git?

Tags: git

If I simply do "checkout some_commit" it will switch me to this commit. But what I need is to stay on the current branch (master to be specific) and totally replace all files in it with files from some_commit. How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`git reset --hard <commit>`

(I'm sure this is a duplicate, but don't have time to search.)

Comment: Be sure to do this after making current the branch you want to replace

Comment: How to create a new commit when this happens? Like StackExchange edits, "Rollback to sha"